# Ltablex: Bug on newpage

Tags: longtable, ltablex

when I get Tables over multiple pages I get the following problem:

[image]

So the footer on page two is shifted down, and the first row on the third page is wrong. Although everything works on top of page 2.

I know that I have to compile it multiple times, that's not the problem.

Full TEX:

```
%&pdflatex
%Schriftgrösse, Layout, Papierformat, Art des Dokumentes
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a3paper, landscape]{scrartcl}
%Einstellungen der Seitenränder
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,includeheadfoot, landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%neue Rechtschreibung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%Umlaute ermöglichen
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%Kopf- und Fusszeile
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
%Bilder
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
%Tabellen
\usepackage{ltablex}
\keepXColumns
\usepackage{bigstrut}
%Linie oben
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%Linie unten
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\newcommand{\wrap}[1]{\parbox{0.08\linewidth}{\vspace{1mm}#1\vspace{2mm}}}
%Header
\headsep = 45pt
\lhead{\textbf{\huge Planjournal}\newline\linebreak[4]\textbf{Projekt: }EH Schermen\qquad\textbf{Projekt-Nr.: }2029\qquad\textbf{Projektleiter:} Unbekannt Unbekannt}\chead{}\rhead{}
%Footer
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.3pt}% default is 0pt
\lfoot{plan.ingenta.ch}\cfoot{\today}\rfoot{Seite \thepage}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \vspace{2cm}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|X|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
            \hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
\textbf{Plannummer}&\textbf{Sektor}&\textbf{Bezeichnung}&\textbf{Art}&\textbf{gez.}&\textbf{Planummer Projektraum}&\textbf{Listen}&\textbf{CAD-File}&\textbf{Korrex. out}&\textbf{Korrex. in}&\textbf{Plan raus}&\textbf{Index}\\
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
\textbf{Plannummer} & \textbf{Sektor} & \textbf{Bezeichnung} & \textbf{Art} & \textbf{gez.} & \textbf{Planummer Projektraum} & \textbf{Listen} & \textbf{CAD-File} & \textbf{Korrex. out} & \textbf{Korrex. in} & \textbf{Plan raus}&\textbf{Index}\\
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
\hline
\endhead
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
 & Rampengebäude &  & Unbekannt & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
 &  &  & Unbekannt & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
 & Rampengebäude &  & Unbekannt & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
 & Rampengebäude &  & Unbekannt & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
1 &  & Aushub & Aushub & rou &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
2 &  & Spundwand & Unbekannt & mun &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
3 &  & Entwässerungskonzept & Unbekannt & rou &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
4 &  & Pfahlplan & Unbekannt & mos &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
10 & Retetionsbecken & Bodenplatte, Wände + Decke & Schalung & zin &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-08-20 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
11 & Retetionsbecken & Bodenplatte & Bewehrung & zin &  & \wrap{Unbekannt } &   &  &  & 2014-08-20 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
12 & Retetionsbecken & Wände & Bewehrung & zin &  & \wrap{Unbekannt } &   &  &  & 2014-08-25 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
13 & Retetionsbecken & Decke & Schalung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
14 & Retetionsbecken & Decke & Bewehrung & xxx &  & \wrap{Unbekannt } &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
50 & Betriebsgebäude & Pfähle & Schalung & zin &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-08-13 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
51 & Betriebsgebäude &  & Schalung & mos &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-08-14 & \wrap{A 2014-08-14}\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
52 & Betriebsgebäude & Bodenplatte & Schalung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  & 2014-10-03 & 2014-10-06 & \wrap{C 2014-10-06}\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
53 & Betriebsgebäude & Bodenplatte & Bewehrung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-10-06 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
54 & Betriebsgebäude & Wände und Stützen & Schalung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  & 2014-11-04 & 2014-11-04 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
55 & Betriebsgebäude & Wände und Stützen & Bewehrung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-11-04 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
56 & Betriebsgebäude & Decke über Erdgeschoss & Schalung & xxx &  & 0 &   & 2014-10-28 & 2014-11-11 & 2014-11-11 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
57 & Betriebsgebäude & Decke über Erdgeschoss & Bewehrung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-11-11 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
58 & Betriebsgebäude & Wände im 1.Obergeschoss & Schalung & mos &  & 0 &   & 2014-12-08 & 2014-12-19 &  & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
59 & Betriebsgebäude & Wände im 1.Obergeschoss & Bewehrung & mos &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2015-01-22 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
60 & Betriebsgebäude & Decke uber 1.Obergeschoss & Schalung & mos &  & 0 &   & 2014-12-08 & 2015-01-26 &  & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
61 & Betriebsgebäude & Decke uber 1.Obergeschoss & Bewehrung & mos &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
62 & Rampengebäude & Wände im 2.Obergeschoss & Schalung & mos &  & 0 &   & 2015-01-05 &  &  & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
62 & Betriebsgebäude & Wände im 2.Obergeschoss & Schalung & mos &  & 0 &   & 2015-01-05 &  &  & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
63 & Rampengebäude & Wände im 2.Obergeschoss & Bewehrung & mos &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
64 & Rampengebäude & Decke über 2.Obergeschoss & Schalung & mos &  & 0 &   & 2015-01-05 &  &  & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
64 & Betriebsgebäude & Decke über 2.Obergeschoss & Schalung & mos &  & 0 &   & 2015-01-05 &  &  & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
65 & Rampengebäude & Decke über 2.Obergeschoss & Bewehrung & mos &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
100 & Stützmauer & etappe1 & Schalung & zin &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-08-11 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
101 & Stützmauer & etappe1 & Bewehrung & zin &  & \wrap{Unbekannt } &   &  &  & 2014-08-18 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
102 & Stützmauer & etappe2+3 & Schalung & zin &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
103 & Stützmauer & etappe2+3 & Bewehrung & gjo &  & \wrap{Unbekannt } &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
121 & Baumeister Aushub & Pfähle & Schalung & zin &  & 0 & PL-121  &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
200 & Rampengebäude & Liftgrube-Bodenplatte-1 & Schalung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-08-11 & \wrap{A 2014-08-11}\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
201 & Rampengebäude & Liftgrube-Bodenplatte-1 & Bewehrung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-08-07 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
202 & Rampengebäude & Bodenplatte & Bewehrung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-08-07 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
203 & Rampengebäude & Kabelschacht & Schalung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-08-07 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
204 & Rampengebäude & Kabelschacht & Bewehrung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-08-07 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
205 & Rampengebäude UG & Wände & Schalung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
206 & Rampengebäude UG & Wände & Schalung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-10-02 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
207 & Rampengebäude UG & Wände 5.Etappe & Schalung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-10-02 & \wrap{A 2014-10-02}\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
208 & Rampengebäude UG & Wände 5.Etappe & Bewehrung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
209 & Rampengebäude UG &  & Bewehrung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  & 2014-11-04 &  & \wrap{B 2014-08-20}\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
210 & Rampengebäude UG & Decke 1+2 Etappe & Bewehrung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-09-01 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
211 &  &  & Unbekannt & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
212 & RampengebäudeUG & Wände Zentrale Wechselrichter & Schalung und Bewehrung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
213 & RampengebäudeUG & Rampenfundament und Rampenwände & Bewehrung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-10-09 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
216 & Rampengebäude UG & Lichtschächte und Treppe & Schalung & gjo &  & 0 & PL-216  &  & 2014-11-18 & 2014-11-18 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
216 & Rampengebäude & Stützmauer und Lichtschächte & Schalung & xxx &  & 0 &   & 2014-11-07 &  &  & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
217 & Rampengebäude & Lichtschächte und Treppe & Bewehrung & mos &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-11-18 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
218 & Rampengebäude & Brüstungen im Erdgeschoss & Schalung & mos &  & 0 &   & 2014-11-03 & 2014-12-10 & 2014-11-12 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
218.1 & Rampengebäude & Koordinatenplan Brüstungen & Schalung & mos &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-11-27 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
219 & Rampengebäude & Brüstungen im Erdgeschoss & Bewehrung & mos &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-11-12 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
220 & Rampengebäude & Nebenraum-Disponibel & Schalung & mos &  & 0 &   & 2014-10-31 & 2014-12-10 & 2014-12-10 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
221 & Rampengebäude & Nebenraum-Disponibel & Bewehrung & mos &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-12-10 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
222 & Rampengebäude & Liftwände und Decke im Ergeschoss & Schalung & mos &  & 0 &   & 2014-10-31 &  & 2014-12-10 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
223 & Rampengebäude & Liftwände und Decke im Ergeschoss & Bewehrung & mos &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-12-10 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
225 & Rampengebäude & Rampe Seite Wölflistrasse & Schalung & mos &  & 0 &   & 2014-11-10 & 2014-11-24 & 2014-12-10 & \wrap{A 2014-12-10}\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
226 & Rampengebäude & Rampe Seite Wölflistrasse & Bewehrung & mos &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-12-10 & \wrap{B 2014-12-10}\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
227 & Rampengebäude & Rampe Seite Stützmauer & Schalung & mos &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-12-05 & 0\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
228 & Rampengebäude & Rampe Seite Stützmauer & Bewehrung & mos &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-12-05 & 0\\
\hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your input is appearing on the site as `Rampe Seite WÃ¶lflistrasse` it  appears to have been encoded as utf8 twice. Can you repost the original text?

Comment: If I run your example code and ignore errors from badly encoded characters, the heading on page 3  does not show any problem overprinting as shown in your image.

Comment: Thank you for your help! When I run the code I don't get any errors from these characters, they are even correct in the PDF.

Comment: When I remove all the "special" characters, I get a correct table, but the footer is still shifted down on page 2 and 3.

Comment: Can you repost your test file in a form that does not generate errors. As It is, it does not show the problem you describe and generates lots of utf8 encoding errors so it is impossible to help much.

Comment: Sorry. I changed it. As it is now, I still get both problems.

Comment: `\\[-12px]` You have negative space all over the table! That is bound to generate overprinting, just not doing that would help, but what was the intention?

Comment: OK, i removed these. (I wanted to vertical-align the text in the middle of the cell. How to do it correctly?) Still the footers aren't at the same position on the pages.

Comment: The table foot is attached to the bottom of the table so will move up or down depending on the table content and page breaking, it is not like a page foot that stays in the same place on every page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines

```
&&&&&&&&&&&\\[-12px]
```

Introduce negative space all over the table, and depending where the page breaks will cause the following row to overprint the header. Removing all these lines causes the problem to go.

In addition there is a warning from fancyhdr:

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (17.0pt): 
 Make it at least 46.40985pt.
```

So I added

```
\setlength\headheight{50pt}
```

Resulting in:

```
%&pdflatex
%Schriftgrösse, Layout, Papierformat, Art des Dokumentes
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a3paper, landscape]{scrartcl}
%Einstellungen der Seitenränder
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,includeheadfoot, landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%neue Rechtschreibung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%Umlaute ermöglichen
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%Kopf- und Fusszeile
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength\headheight{50pt}
\fancyhf{}
%Bilder
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
%Tabellen
\usepackage{ltablex}
\keepXColumns
\usepackage{bigstrut}
%Linie oben
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%Linie unten
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\newcommand{\wrap}[1]{\parbox{0.08\linewidth}{\vspace{1mm}#1\vspace{2mm}}}
%Header
\headsep = 45pt
\lhead{\textbf{\huge Planjournal}\newline\linebreak[4]\textbf{Projekt: }EH Schermen\qquad\textbf{Projekt-Nr.: }2029\qquad\textbf{Projektleiter:} Unbekannt Unbekannt}\chead{}\rhead{}
%Footer
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.3pt}% default is 0pt
\lfoot{plan.ingenta.ch}\cfoot{\today}\rfoot{Seite \thepage}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \vspace{2cm}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|X|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
            \hline

\textbf{Plannummer}&\textbf{Sektor}&\textbf{Bezeichnung}&\textbf{Art}&\textbf{gez.}&\textbf{Planummer Projektraum}&\textbf{Listen}&\textbf{CAD-File}&\textbf{Korrex. out}&\textbf{Korrex. in}&\textbf{Plan raus}&\textbf{Index}\\

\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline

\textbf{Plannummer} & \textbf{Sektor} & \textbf{Bezeichnung} & \textbf{Art} & \textbf{gez.} & \textbf{Planummer Projektraum} & \textbf{Listen} & \textbf{CAD-File} & \textbf{Korrex. out} & \textbf{Korrex. in} & \textbf{Plan raus}&\textbf{Index}\\

\hline
\endhead
\endfoot
\endlastfoot

 & Rampengebäude &  & Unbekannt & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline

 &  &  & Unbekannt & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline

 & Rampengebäude &  & Unbekannt & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline

 & Rampengebäude &  & Unbekannt & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline

1 &  & Aushub & Aushub & rou &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline

2 &  & Spundwand & Unbekannt & mun &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline

3 &  & Entwässerungskonzept & Unbekannt & rou &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline

4 &  & Pfahlplan & Unbekannt & mos &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline

10 & Retetionsbecken & Bodenplatte, Wände + Decke & Schalung & zin &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-08-20 & 0\\
\hline

11 & Retetionsbecken & Bodenplatte & Bewehrung & zin &  & \wrap{Unbekannt } &   &  &  & 2014-08-20 & 0\\
\hline

12 & Retetionsbecken & Wände & Bewehrung & zin &  & \wrap{Unbekannt } &   &  &  & 2014-08-25 & 0\\
\hline

13 & Retetionsbecken & Decke & Schalung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline

14 & Retetionsbecken & Decke & Bewehrung & xxx &  & \wrap{Unbekannt } &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline

50 & Betriebsgebäude & Pfähle & Schalung & zin &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-08-13 & 0\\
\hline

51 & Betriebsgebäude &  & Schalung & mos &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-08-14 & \wrap{A 2014-08-14}\\
\hline

52 & Betriebsgebäude & Bodenplatte & Schalung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  & 2014-10-03 & 2014-10-06 & \wrap{C 2014-10-06}\\
\hline

53 & Betriebsgebäude & Bodenplatte & Bewehrung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-10-06 & 0\\
\hline

54 & Betriebsgebäude & Wände und Stützen & Schalung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  & 2014-11-04 & 2014-11-04 & 0\\
\hline

55 & Betriebsgebäude & Wände und Stützen & Bewehrung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-11-04 & 0\\
\hline

56 & Betriebsgebäude & Decke über Erdgeschoss & Schalung & xxx &  & 0 &   & 2014-10-28 & 2014-11-11 & 2014-11-11 & 0\\
\hline

57 & Betriebsgebäude & Decke über Erdgeschoss & Bewehrung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-11-11 & 0\\
\hline

58 & Betriebsgebäude & Wände im 1.Obergeschoss & Schalung & mos &  & 0 &   & 2014-12-08 & 2014-12-19 &  & 0\\
\hline

59 & Betriebsgebäude & Wände im 1.Obergeschoss & Bewehrung & mos &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2015-01-22 & 0\\
\hline

60 & Betriebsgebäude & Decke uber 1.Obergeschoss & Schalung & mos &  & 0 &   & 2014-12-08 & 2015-01-26 &  & 0\\
\hline

61 & Betriebsgebäude & Decke uber 1.Obergeschoss & Bewehrung & mos &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline

62 & Rampengebäude & Wände im 2.Obergeschoss & Schalung & mos &  & 0 &   & 2015-01-05 &  &  & 0\\
\hline

62 & Betriebsgebäude & Wände im 2.Obergeschoss & Schalung & mos &  & 0 &   & 2015-01-05 &  &  & 0\\
\hline

63 & Rampengebäude & Wände im 2.Obergeschoss & Bewehrung & mos &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline

64 & Rampengebäude & Decke über 2.Obergeschoss & Schalung & mos &  & 0 &   & 2015-01-05 &  &  & 0\\
\hline

64 & Betriebsgebäude & Decke über 2.Obergeschoss & Schalung & mos &  & 0 &   & 2015-01-05 &  &  & 0\\
\hline

65 & Rampengebäude & Decke über 2.Obergeschoss & Bewehrung & mos &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline

100 & Stützmauer & etappe1 & Schalung & zin &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-08-11 & 0\\
\hline

101 & Stützmauer & etappe1 & Bewehrung & zin &  & \wrap{Unbekannt } &   &  &  & 2014-08-18 & 0\\
\hline

102 & Stützmauer & etappe2+3 & Schalung & zin &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline

103 & Stützmauer & etappe2+3 & Bewehrung & gjo &  & \wrap{Unbekannt } &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline

121 & Baumeister Aushub & Pfähle & Schalung & zin &  & 0 & PL-121  &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline

200 & Rampengebäude & Liftgrube-Bodenplatte-1 & Schalung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-08-11 & \wrap{A 2014-08-11}\\
\hline

201 & Rampengebäude & Liftgrube-Bodenplatte-1 & Bewehrung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-08-07 & 0\\
\hline

202 & Rampengebäude & Bodenplatte & Bewehrung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-08-07 & 0\\
\hline

203 & Rampengebäude & Kabelschacht & Schalung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-08-07 & 0\\
\hline

204 & Rampengebäude & Kabelschacht & Bewehrung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-08-07 & 0\\
\hline

205 & Rampengebäude UG & Wände & Schalung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline

206 & Rampengebäude UG & Wände & Schalung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-10-02 & 0\\
\hline

207 & Rampengebäude UG & Wände 5.Etappe & Schalung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-10-02 & \wrap{A 2014-10-02}\\
\hline

208 & Rampengebäude UG & Wände 5.Etappe & Bewehrung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline

209 & Rampengebäude UG &  & Bewehrung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  & 2014-11-04 &  & \wrap{B 2014-08-20}\\
\hline

210 & Rampengebäude UG & Decke 1+2 Etappe & Bewehrung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-09-01 & 0\\
\hline

211 &  &  & Unbekannt & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline

212 & RampengebäudeUG & Wände Zentrale Wechselrichter & Schalung und Bewehrung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  &  & 0\\
\hline

213 & RampengebäudeUG & Rampenfundament und Rampenwände & Bewehrung & xxx &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-10-09 & 0\\
\hline

216 & Rampengebäude UG & Lichtschächte und Treppe & Schalung & gjo &  & 0 & PL-216  &  & 2014-11-18 & 2014-11-18 & 0\\
\hline

216 & Rampengebäude & Stützmauer und Lichtschächte & Schalung & xxx &  & 0 &   & 2014-11-07 &  &  & 0\\
\hline

217 & Rampengebäude & Lichtschächte und Treppe & Bewehrung & mos &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-11-18 & 0\\
\hline

218 & Rampengebäude & Brüstungen im Erdgeschoss & Schalung & mos &  & 0 &   & 2014-11-03 & 2014-12-10 & 2014-11-12 & 0\\
\hline

218.1 & Rampengebäude & Koordinatenplan Brüstungen & Schalung & mos &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-11-27 & 0\\
\hline

219 & Rampengebäude & Brüstungen im Erdgeschoss & Bewehrung & mos &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-11-12 & 0\\
\hline

220 & Rampengebäude & Nebenraum-Disponibel & Schalung & mos &  & 0 &   & 2014-10-31 & 2014-12-10 & 2014-12-10 & 0\\
\hline

221 & Rampengebäude & Nebenraum-Disponibel & Bewehrung & mos &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-12-10 & 0\\
\hline

222 & Rampengebäude & Liftwände und Decke im Ergeschoss & Schalung & mos &  & 0 &   & 2014-10-31 &  & 2014-12-10 & 0\\
\hline

223 & Rampengebäude & Liftwände und Decke im Ergeschoss & Bewehrung & mos &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-12-10 & 0\\
\hline

225 & Rampengebäude & Rampe Seite Wölflistrasse & Schalung & mos &  & 0 &   & 2014-11-10 & 2014-11-24 & 2014-12-10 & \wrap{A 2014-12-10}\\
\hline

226 & Rampengebäude & Rampe Seite Wölflistrasse & Bewehrung & mos &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-12-10 & \wrap{B 2014-12-10}\\
\hline

227 & Rampengebäude & Rampe Seite Stützmauer & Schalung & mos &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-12-05 & 0\\
\hline

228 & Rampengebäude & Rampe Seite Stützmauer & Bewehrung & mos &  & 0 &   &  &  & 2014-12-05 & 0\\
\hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! But now, how can I vertical align the text in the cell?

Comment: @heysamhey perhaps `\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}` before the table It depends what effect you want. (or `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}` )

Comment: Yes, the second command did exactly what i wanted. Thank you very much!